# $a$ is not an associate of $b$ in correct math expression

Tags: propositional-calculus

**Background:**

**Definition:**  An element $a\in R$ is an **associate** of $b\in R$ provided $a=bu$ for some unit $u.$

**Questions:**

I want to ask in math notation, to say that $a$ is not an associate of $b$ means that for every unit $u$, $a\neq bu$  Is that the correct negation?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Yes it is correct

Comment: @Kroki ah kk. Thank you.

Comment: But that is not "notation"...

Comment: @ArturoMagidin i don't know what to call it.

Comment: You are asking about the negation/meaning of the term, not about how to represent it symbolically (which is what "notation" is). In particular, note the description of the `notation` tag: "Questions on the meaning, history, and usage of mathematical symbols and notation. Please remember to mention where (book, paper, webpage, etc.) you encountered any mathematical notation you are asking about." You are not asking about any of that.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I edited the title of my post.

Comment: This is a question about propositional calculus, i.e. how to negate an existential statement. It is expected that one already knows such basic logic before studying abstract algebra, so you may be trying to run before you have learned to walk.

Comment: @BillDubuque I have taken courses in symbolic logic.  I don't think doing thousands of different translation exercises is going to help me with language issues in abstract algebra.  i never had much trouble with real or complex analysis.  There is something about the précision of language thar trips me up in algebra.

Comment: It's because the objects tend to be more abstract here than in calculus so you are forced to rely on symbolic reasoning rather than less rigorous (geometric) intuition.

Comment: @BillDubuque wait, so real, complex and functional analysis including point set topology are geometric on nature compare to abstract algebra?  I just find the définitions in abstract algebra, I find sometimes the definition difficult to translate to symbolic logic notations.

Comment: Your said real/complex analysis above, not point set topology. It is quite common to hear students complain that they have much more difficulty developing intuition for  algebra vs. analysis.

Comment: @BillDubuque I saw in an interview where Terrence Tao said it took him à while to wrap his head around algebra and topology.  I don't feel so bad after hearing that.

Comment: Evolution didn't wire our brains for such very abstract reasoning. We have to do that on our own.

Comment: Please stop using MathJax to format text. Use markdown instead.

Comment: @Seth, Bill Dubuque is trying to help you. From the other post I helped you with, it's clear that applying logical operations to text troubles you. It doesn't need to. I would take his suggestion at face value, and spend a few hours ironing out troubles in stating propositions, their converses, negations, contrapositives, etc. Your life will get easier.